# Using a project file as a parameter in MSBuild with Hudson

Tags: msbuild, hudson

I'm currently using the Hudson build system with MSBuild steps. As part of the build, I have a project file with various targets in, one of which is to start a build with visual studio. However, I need to pass through a seperate project file to this target in order for it to build, but I keep getting the exception 'MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.'

I believe this is because the system is unable to calculate which project is supposed to be the parameter, and which the top-level target? If so, is there anyway to resolve this.

Here is a snippet of the target project file:

```
 <Target Name="VisualStudioTask">
    <!-- Required Properties:
    $(BuildType)
    $(ConfigurationSetup)
    $(Solution)-->
    <Exec Command="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe $(BuildType) $(ConfigurationSetup) $(Solution)" />
  </Target>
```

The MSBuild step calling this looks like this:

```
/t:VisualStudioTask -p:BuildType="/Build" p:ConfigurationSetup="Release" -p:Solution="%22..\MyProject.vcproj%22"
```

Many thanks
Chris

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out, the problem was that I'd left out a '-' when declaring the 'ConfigurationSetup' parameter, so if you look in my original example it has this:

```
/t:VisualStudioTask -p:BuildType="/Build" p:ConfigurationSetup="Release" -p:Solution="%22..\MyProject.vcproj%22"
```

When it should have this..

```
/t:VisualStudioTask -p:BuildType="/Build" -p:ConfigurationSetup="Release" -p:Solution="%22..\MyProject.vcproj%22"
```